# Compile a .cpp File on Linux into a PE for Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compilation, cross-compiling

I've read through plenty of discussion posts about this topic, but I can't seem to find an answer. I've looked at mingw for compiling, but my code always dumps out a "narrowing conversion of '' from 'int' to 'char'. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: "*my code always dumps out a "narrowing conversion"*" - then you should post your actual code.  But what does this have to do with cross compiling between platforms?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet, details of your toolchain, and the exact error message.

Comment: i doubt you have all stuff installed. you need toolchain and all other stuff. And for some reason i doubt you have it all inplace. Monjaro linux is most light on that